# {$link->getPageLink("$order_process.php", true)} not working outside blockcart template

Tags: php, e-commerce, smarty, prestashop

I'm trying to add a second link to the order process outside of the blockcart module, but when I use

```
{$link->getPageLink("$order_process", true)|escape:'html'}
```

to generate the URL, it gives the following invalid URL:
http://petiteannee.ch/en/index.php?controller=
When it should give:
http://petiteannee.ch/en/order

It works fine in the blockcart module.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because the variable $order_process is not defined. Try with:

```
{$link->getPageLink('order', true)|escape:'html'}
```